# Как правильно вносить данные в таблицу с индексом на уникальные пары значений?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

У меня есть таблица с индексом `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, lesson_id)`. Я хотел бы использовать этот индекс для исключения необходимости предварительной проверки таблицы на наличие вносимых значений. Но добавление такой записи в Wordpress всегда вызывает ошибку. Например, такую: `` Ошибка базы данных WordPress: [Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'] INSERT INTO `w3junique_lessons_visits` (`user_id`, `lesson_id`) VALUES (1, '1') ``

Как правильно поступать в таких случаях? Может быть нужно добавить что-то к запросу `INSERT` помимо значений? Сейчас добавление происходит через метод `$wpdb->insert($table, $params)`.

Comment: Значения в `PRIMARY KEY` должны быть уникальными, ошибка возникает в следствие того, что Вы пытаетесь добавить еще одну запись с такими же значениями.

Comment: *Как правильно поступать в таких случаях?* Обрабатывать эту ошибку. *Я хотел бы использовать этот индекс для исключения необходимости предварительной проверки таблицы на наличие вносимых значений.* Уникальный индекс служит не для проверки, а для блокирования попытки вставить запись-дубликат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо изменить SQL-запрос, добавив слово `IGNORE` после `INSERT`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `unique_visits` 
(`user_id`, `lesson_id`) 
VALUES (10, 20)
```